# Multiple Producer single consumer

Tags: c, queue, consumer, producer

I am having trouble understanding the multiple producers and single consumer problem. I am working on an assignment and I am unsure on how creating two producers work.. I understand how the single producer/consumer problem works but I cannot understand how to go about multiple producers would I need to create two separate threads for each producer, if that is the case how does filling a queue up with their 'produced data' would one of the producers need to be asleep while the other producer fills say a single data item and then they switch back and forth until the queue buffer is full?

Just looking for an explanation as I do not understand exactly how this would work (before someone makes the suggestion I am looking for someone to do my homework thats not the case just looking for helpful insight to clear up my thoughts on this so I can implement it myself)

I have looked at many other questions/topics about this on this and various other websites and still haven't been able to come to a conclusion on my answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Quick example.. It's like a restroom at a gas station. You (the consumer) must get the bathroom key (the mutex/lock) from the attendant (producer) in order to use the resource (restroom). There could be many attendants at the gas station, checking out customers, mopping the floor, etc,, all off doing their own thing waiting for the key to be returned. There could be many consumers at the gas station, pumping gas, buying food, etc,, all off doing their own thing waiting on the restroom to get vacated.  When it is, another consumer can acquire the key use the restroom.

Comment: Okay that's definitely helpful, so what I gather is I just can define the two producer threads, and have them both be 'taking orders' and which ever one gets to it first gets to it first? I wouldn't have to have one of them could be 'working' at the same time but just kind of compete for the ability to do the task?

Comment: The only time that threads need to "compete" is when they have to share a resource. For example, a buffer. The producer threads insert information into the buffer, the consumers take it out. Access to the buffer has to be protected so that 2 producer threads don't write their data to the same place; otherwise you'll end up with corrupted data. Same for the consumer threads... without thread synchronization to the shared resource, you will never have a clearly defined state for the resource, and then chaos ensues. When the threads aren't accessing the shared resource, you want them off doing

Comment: their own thing in parallel,, that's where you get the speed enhancements from threads.  You want the critical section (the part where the threads are accessing the shared resource) to be as small as possible.  If you have a 100 threads, but they spend all their time trying to access a shared resource, you won't be any better off than if you just had 1 thread,, and in fact you'll probably be worse off b/c spinning up threads takes time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using just the `pipe` and `select` system calls to implement a MPSCQ. The following diagram elaborate how it works:

```
<producer-thread-1>  {msg produced in heap}
  \
   \  /* only address of msg objects were sent to pipe[1] */
    \
     pipe[1] >>>(kernel)>>> pipe[0]  <consumer-thread>:
    /                                1. polling from pipe[0]
   /                                 2. restore msg object via address ptr
  /                                  3. process then delete the msg object
<producer-thread-2>  {msg produced in heap}
```

The demo code is in C++ for encapsulating the queue into a class, and no C++11/14/17 features were used. First is the queue class, in template form:

```
// mpscq.hpp
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PTR_SIZE (sizeof(void*))

template<class T> class MPSCQ { // Multi Producer Single Consumer Queue
public:
        MPSCQ() {
                int pipe_fd_set[2];
                pipe(pipe_fd_set); // err-handler omitted for this demo
                _fdProducer = pipe_fd_set[1];
                _fdConsumer = pipe_fd_set[0];
        }
        ~MPSCQ() { /* pipe close omitted for this demo */ }
        int producerPush(const T* t) {
                // will be blocked when pipe is full, should always return PTR_SIZE
                return t == NULL ? 0 : write(_fdProducer, &t, PTR_SIZE);
        }
        T* consumerPoll(int timeout = 1);
private:
        int _selectFdConsumer(int timeout);
private:
        int _fdProducer; // pipe_fd_set[1]
        int _fdConsumer; // pipe_fd_set[0]
};

template<class T> T* MPSCQ<T>::consumerPoll(int timeout) {
        if (_selectFdConsumer(timeout) <= 0) {  // timeout or error
                return NULL;
        }
        char ptr_buff[PTR_SIZE];
        ssize_t r = read(_fdConsumer, ptr_buff, PTR_SIZE);
        if (r <= 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "consumer read EOF or error, r=%d, errno=%d\n", r, errno);
                return NULL;
        }
        T* t;
        memcpy(&t, ptr_buff, PTR_SIZE); // cast received bytes to T*
        return t;
}

template<class T> int MPSCQ<T>::_selectFdConsumer(int timeout) {
        int nfds = _fdConsumer + 1;
        fd_set readfds;
        struct timeval tv;
        while (true) {
                tv.tv_sec = timeout;
                tv.tv_usec = 0;
                FD_ZERO(&readfds);
                FD_SET(_fdConsumer, &readfds);
                int r = select(nfds, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
                if (r < 0 && errno == EINTR) {
                        continue;
                }
                return r;
        }
}
```

Then here comes the test case: 4 producer threads emitting 1..100000, and one consumer thread sums it up.

```
// g++ -o mpscq mpscq.cpp -lpthread
#include "mpscq.hpp"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PER_THREAD_LOOPS        25000
#define SAMPLE_INTERVAL         10000
#define PRODUCER_THREAD_NUM     4

struct TestMsg {
        int _msgId;     // a dummy demo member
        int64_t _val;   // _val < 0 is an end flag
        TestMsg(int msg_id, int64_t val) :
                _msgId(msg_id),
                _val(val) { };
};

static MPSCQ<TestMsg> TEST_QUEUE;

void* functor_producer(void* arg) {
        int* task_seg = (int*) arg;
        TestMsg* msg;
        for (int i = 0; i <= PER_THREAD_LOOPS; ++ i) {
                int64_t id = PER_THREAD_LOOPS * (*task_seg) + i;
                msg = new TestMsg(id, i >= PER_THREAD_LOOPS ? -1 : id + 1);
                TEST_QUEUE.producerPush(msg);
        }
        delete task_seg;
        return NULL;
}

void* functor_consumer(void* arg) {
        int64_t* sum = (int64_t*)arg;
        int msg_cnt = 0;
        int stop_cnt = 0; // for shutdown gracefully
        TestMsg* msg;
        while (true) {
                if ((msg = TEST_QUEUE.consumerPoll()) == NULL) {
                        continue;
                }
                int64_t val = msg->_val;
                delete msg; // this delete is essential to prevent memory leak
                if (val <= 0) {
                        if ((++ stop_cnt) >= PRODUCER_THREAD_NUM) {
                                printf("all done, sum=%ld\n", *sum);
                                break;
                        }
                } else {
                        *sum += val;
                        if ((++ msg_cnt) % SAMPLE_INTERVAL == 0) {
                                printf("msg_cnt=%d, sum=%ld\n", msg_cnt, *sum);
                        }
                }
        }
        return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* const* argv) {
        int64_t sum = 0;
        printf("PTR_SIZE: %d, target: sum(1..%d)\n", PTR_SIZE, PRODUCER_THREAD_NUM * PER_THREAD_LOOPS);
        pthread_t consumer;
        pthread_create(&consumer, NULL, functor_consumer, &sum);
        pthread_t producers[PRODUCER_THREAD_NUM];
        for (int i = 0; i < PRODUCER_THREAD_NUM; ++ i) {
                pthread_create(&producers[i], NULL, functor_producer, new int(i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < PRODUCER_THREAD_NUM; ++ i) {
                pthread_join(producers[i], NULL);
        }
        pthread_join(consumer, NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

A sample test result:

```
$ ./mpscq 
PTR_SIZE: 8, target: sum(1..100000)
msg_cnt=10000, sum=490096931
msg_cnt=20000, sum=888646187
msg_cnt=30000, sum=1282852073
msg_cnt=40000, sum=1606611602
msg_cnt=50000, sum=2088863858
msg_cnt=60000, sum=2573791058
msg_cnt=70000, sum=3180398370
msg_cnt=80000, sum=3768718659
msg_cnt=90000, sum=4336431164
msg_cnt=100000, sum=5000050000
all done, sum=5000050000
```

The MPSCQ implemented here is a message-passing pattern and let the kernel to deal with the complexity of the internal queue operations. A side-effect of the trick is when the work load is heavy, there will be too many `select` calls in the consumer side which will affect the performance significantly.  (In this demo, every time the consumer just fetch 8 bytes. To alleviate it, the consumer should maintain an extra receive buffer.)